# Angular app keeps saying _user is not defined

Tags: django, angular, typescript, getstream-io

I'm building a chat app with Angular and Django using the get stream tutorial. https://getstream.io/blog/realtime-chat-django-angular/

However, I'm trying to run the app to test the join page but it keeps saying property not defined in the constructor which is from the state.service.ts file.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    export declare interface User {
     token: string;
     apiKey: string;
     username: string;
    }

    @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root',
    })

    export class StateService {
     constructor() {}

     private _user: User;

     get user(): User {
      return this._user;
     }

     set user(user: User) {
      this._user = user;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `StateService`, `_user` is not assigned any value, so its value is `undefined`, yet its type is `User`, which means it cannot be `undefined`, it has to be an object with 3 specific fields. You have 4 potential solutions here:

1. Make `_user` nullable. If having undefined user is a legitimate scenario in your case, change your code in the following way:

   ```
   private _user?: User;
   get user(): User|undefined {
    return this._user;
   } 
   set user(user: User|undefined) {
     this._user = user;
   }
   ```
2. Create a dummy user. You can initialize the user with empty fields to begin with:

   ```
   private _user: User = {token:'', apiKey:'', username:''};
   ```
3. Make sure the user is always present by requiring it in the constructor:

   ```
   constructor(user: User) { this._user=user}
   ```
4. Tell TypeScript that you don't care. You can set tsconfig setting [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)  to false, so you won't get the error message. You will still have undefined user though, which means it can crash your script during runtime, so I wouldn't do that.